# EasyAdmin 3 - CollectionField add form entryType options?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, collections, easyadmin

in my CRUD Controller I have a CollectionField which has an entryType option referring to a formType

```php
yield CollectionField::new('drinks', 'Boissons')
  ->setFormTypeOption('by_reference', false)
  ->setEntryType(CommandProductItemType::class);
```

**CommandProductItemType**

```php
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add('product', EntityType::class, [
                'label' => 'Produit',
                'class' => Product::class,
                'choice_label' => 'namePrice',
            ])
            ->add('quantity', IntegerType::class, [
                'label' => 'Quantité',
                'attr' => [
                    'min' => 1
                ]
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => CommandProductItem::class,
            'category' => Category::class
        ]);
    }
```

How can I pass the **category** option to the **CommandProductItemType** from the **CollectionField** item ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit [entry_options option](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#entry-options) from CollectionType field:

```
yield CollectionField::new('drinks', 'Boissons')
  ->setFormTypeOption('entry_options', ['by_reference' => false])
  ->setEntryType(CommandProductItemType::class);
```